# Problem with thumbnails after newly added - PHP on-the-fly method

Tags: php, image-processing, thumbnails

to those that may have read my previous question that got solved a couple minutes ago >.<

The on-the-fly php script works perfectly, but when I went to upload new images into a gallery which I made myself, the images are resized to 150 x 150 for what I wanted... however, when it comes to new images being added it is all black...

[image]

As you can see the three black images that were uploaded to the folder and the directory added to the database.

The other (non-black images) are already resized with image.php.

What is causing this?

If I view the source, the code is fine... the while loop in the PHP generates an output like this:

```
<div class="view-wrap" id="photo-10">
    <div class="view-icon">
        <div class="img-label">
            <a href="#" id="10" class="delete"><img src="img/small-delete.png" /> Delete</a>
        </div>

        <a href="img/events/Paintballing/24251_1395408043148_1170626626_1204038_5382765_n.jpg">
            <img src="image.php?dir=img/events/Paintballing/24251_1395408043148_1170626626_1204038_5382765_n.jpg" alt="" width="110" height="110" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example of one block.

If I view the source (in Firefox) and click on the image.php?dir=img/events/Paintballing/24251_1395408043148_1170626626_1204038_5382765_n.jpg by exmaple, I can see the thumbnail at it's 150 x 150 size but in the layout, it shows a black thumbnail...

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT:

```
<?php 

$dir = $_GET['dir'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

$create = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150); 

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir);

imagecopyresampled($create, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($create, null, 100); 

?>
```

This is image.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your post.

Are you positive that the image is a jpg/jpeg that your uploading.

Try changing to the following

```
<?php 

$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($dir, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
switch($ext)
{
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jpg':
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir);
    break;
    case 'png':
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($dir);
    break;
    case 'gif':
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($dir);
    break;
}
if(isset(img))
{
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
    $create = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150); 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir);
    imagecopyresampled($create, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($create, null, 100); 
}else
{
   echo sprintf('Unable to process image, Unknown format %s',$ext);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stretching the images why not add a border?

Here's the function

```
    function resize_to_canvas($filename,$canvas_w=100,$canvas_h=225){
list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($filename);

$original_overcanvas_w = $width/$canvas_w;
$original_overcanvas_h = $height/$canvas_h;

$dst_w = round($width/max($original_overcanvas_w,$original_overcanvas_h),0);
$dst_h = round($height/max($original_overcanvas_w,$original_overcanvas_h),0);

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($canvas_w, $canvas_h);
$background = imagecolorallocate($dst_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($dst_image, 0, 0, $background);

$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, ($canvas_w-$dst_w)/2, ($canvas_h-$dst_h)/2, 0, 0, $dst_w, $dst_h, $width, $height);
imagegif($dst_image, $filename);
imagedestroy($dst_image);}
```

This function will replace the original file but is easily modified to create a new thumbnail image. Just change the file name the line imagegif($dst_image, $filename);